# Pandas complicated duplicate removal with three comparisons to other rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, duplicates, vectorization

so I am looking for a "pandas-idiomatic" way to remove duplicates from a pandas dataframe, but I couldn't find any examples or other SO threads where the comparisons to determine duplicates are the same I need to perform. To give a quick example, this is what is considered a duplicate in my case:

```
   PLAYER1  PLAYER2  GAMETYPE  GAME_TIME
0      Ken      Bob    Attack        123
1      Bob      Ken   Defense        123
```

In short - the values of the first two columns need to be "the same but switched places". The "GAMETYPE" would need to have opposite value (if the first is "attack", then the second is "defense", other values exist but only these 2 can cause duplicates). the last column, GAME_TIME, needs to be the same. Normally the last column would be sufficient, however the problem is that this would very rarely cause incorrect removal due to collision with unrelated row, so to prevent that I need to include the other conditions too.

I could of course write some sort of an atrocious nested loop to take care of this, but I would love to know if there's a way of doing it in a vectorized fashion (maybe even with numpy), as this is the entire point of pandas, or at least a big portion of the point ;) Love to hear your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your player names alphabetically, forcing the format to be:

- `First_Name_Alphabetically, Second_Name, Defense, Time`

And then drop the duplicates.

```
mask = df['PLAYER1'].gt(df['PLAYER2'])
df['GAMETYPE'] = df['GAMETYPE'].mask(mask, 'Defense')
df[['PLAYER1', 'PLAYER2']] = np.sort(df[['PLAYER1', 'PLAYER2']])
df = df.drop_duplicates()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  PLAYER1 PLAYER2 GAMETYPE  GAME_TIME
0     Bob     Ken  Defense        123
```

---

This is assuming you don't have both Attack and Defense for every Game. Otherwise you should just drop all `Attack` or all `Defense` rows.

Comment: yeah, sadly due to some niche cases I can't drop all Defense rows, tried that and there are very rare artifacts, but they exist. What you wrote is a bit over my head, can you explain how exactly does that work? What are the masks and such